# Retrieving a string from an index of an array, but it's not working

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

So, my code is supposed to look at in input file, the Strings it contains, split them wherever there is a space and out output the Strings separately. I tried using an array to assign those Strings that I split to variables, so that way I can access them when I want to print them out but I keep getting,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
at Coma.main(Coma.java:26)
```

Can someone please help me? Please excuse my formatting of this question, for this is my first time using StackOverflow.

here's my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException;

public class Coma {

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String SENTENCE;
    int NUM_LINES;
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(new File("coma.in"));
    NUM_LINES=sc.nextInt();

    for(int i=0;i<NUM_LINES;i++){
        SENTENCE=sc.nextLine();
        String [] temp;
        String delimiter=" ";
        temp=SENTENCE.split(delimiter);
        String year= temp[0];
        String word=temp[1];

        System.out.println("Nurse: Sir you've been in a coma since " + year     + "\nMe: How's my favorite " + word + " doing?");
    }
}

}
```

Here's the input from the file coma.in

```
3
1495 Constantinople
1962 JFK
1990 USSR
```

Comment: Are you sure that `temp` holds more than one element? You should check first that the `split` call actually splits something (and does not return an array of size 1)

Comment: The problem is with your input data

Comment: please provide some lines from your file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it

Comment: If the number of lines integer is in a line of its own, you might wanna add a `sc.nextLine();` before the loop, as the `sc.nextInt();` does not move the `Scanner` to the next line. Thus the first `sc.nextLine();` inside the loop would just read the (empty) rest of the `NUM_LINES` line.

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb I added the lines from my file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely with your coma.in file format.
However, assuming a correct file formatted like so:

> **data.txt**
>
> 20 team
>
> 10 dog

You could simplify your code to this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
        // default delimiter is whitespace (Character.isWhitespace)
        while (sc.hasNext()) { // true if another token to read
             System.out.println("Nurse: Sir you've been in a coma since "
                     + sc.next() + "\nMe: How's my favorite "
                     + sc.next() + " doing?");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file format is sth like:

```
2
1981 x
1982 y
```

Then

```
sc.nextInt();  // only moves sc past the next token, NOT beyond the line separator
```

will only read the `2` and stop right there, and **NOT** consume the newline! Thus, in order to read the next line (`1981 x`), you have to add another `sc.nextLine()` to actually consume the (empty) string after the 2 in order to get to the next line. You are then splitting the empty string which in turn leads to the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as the resulting array is only of length `1`:

```
//...
NUM_LINES=sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();  // add this line; 

for(int i=0;i<NUM_LINES;i++){
    SENTENCE=sc.nextLine();
    //...
```

Because of this behaviour of the `nextInt`, `nextFloat`. etc. methods, I tend to prefer using `nextLine` and the `parse...` methods:

```
NUM_LINES=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine().strip());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace :

```
NUM_LINES=sc.nextInt();
```

by :

```
NUM_LINES=Integer.valueOf(sc.nextLine());
```

And it will work fine.